# Stretch buttons in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, button, stretch

I'm working on an app where I have 2 buttons.
They need to be taking up the whole screen (side by side).
How can I accomplish this with jQuery Mobile?

I've searched around, but the solutions didn't work.
Examples:
- 
-

This is the code of my buttons

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-inline="true">
            <a href="#toevoegen" data-iconpos="top" data-icon="plus" data-role="button" id="btnBalancePlus"></a>
            <a href="#toevoegen" data-iconpos="top" data-icon="minus" data-role="button" id="btnBalanceMin"></a>
        </div>
```

Any solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just using CSS?

Apply this to the container and/or the button:

```
.the_button {width:100%;}
```